# How can I route to multiple NodeJS applications using Nginx?

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have 2 NodeJS applications running locally on port 3000 and 3001. I'm trying to route to them individually by using my_ip/tilbudsfinneren for one of them, and my_ip/hms for the other one.

My sites-available file looks like this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/my_ip/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name my_ip www.my_ip;

        location /tilbudsfinneren {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /hms {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }


}
```

Whenever I try to reach my_ip/hms or my_ip/hms/ping it does not reach the NodeJS application, I get get "Cannot GET /hms". Is there an issue with my nginx configuration, or is there maybe something else wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to serve both apps as reverse proxy you must use rewrite methods in both locations.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location /tilbudsfinneren/ {
        rewrite ^/tilbudsfinneren/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        #other config... 
    }

    location /hms/ {
        rewrite ^/hms/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
    }
}
```